# background of BottomNavBar is blurred, persistent_bottom_nav_bar_v2

Tags: android, flutter

I was developing an application recently and encountered this issue while using a plugin, if anyone encountered similar issue or can provide any kind of help It would be really appreciated.
The background of the Bottomnavbar goes blur at the last index only, works fine on every other index.

I tried changing the colours of the background but still it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok  I think you should to type the code in the right way
so you can try this code to solve your issue ,
In this example I used GetX package.

student_controller.dart

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class StudentController extends GetxController{
  int index = 0;
  changeTo(int i){
    index = i;
    update();
  }
}
```

bottom_nav_of_student.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BottomNavigationBarOfStudent extends StatefulWidget {
  final StudentController controller;
  const BottomNavigationBarOfStudent({Key? key, required this.controller})
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<BottomNavigationBarOfStudent> createState() =>
      _BottomNavigationBarOfStudentState();
}

class _BottomNavigationBarOfStudentState
    extends State<BottomNavigationBarOfStudent> {
  var index = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var controller = widget.controller;
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      backgroundColor:  const Color(0xB3ffffff),
      selectedItemColor: const Color(0xffff9800),
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      iconSize: 30,
      elevation: 0,
      currentIndex: controller.index,
      onTap: (i) {
        setState(() {
          controller.changeTo(i);
          // this.index = index;
        });
      },
      //items of BottomNavigationBer Widget
      items: const [
        //home item
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
          label: 'الرئيسية',
        ),
        //notification item
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.notifications_outlined,
          ),
          label: 'الاشعارات',
        ),
        //orders item
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home_repair_service_outlined),
          label: 'الحجوزات',
        ),
        //bookmarks item
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark_outline),
          label: 'الحفوظات',
        ),
        //account item
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.person_2_outlined),
          label: 'الحساب',
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I hope that code solved your issue :)

Comment: I think this would work, but the issue will still remain, I want to use the persistent_nav_bar_v2 package because it is simpler and ready made designs.

Comment: Oh! sorry I don't knew about that , try to search on youTube may be solve your issue